# How to transform an integer to date type in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, date, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where the date columns have numbers like "2111" where 21 means 2021 and 11 means November. First of all how to separate 21 and 11? Second how to transform It to date data type?
Thank you

Comment: Is the "date" actually a number like ``2111`` or is it a *string* like ``"2111"`` instead? Is the width fixed, i.e. would "October 2009" be represented as ``0910`` or ``910``?

Comment: It is an integer. Not a string. And have two columns that I want to transform

Comment: and I have the data only for 2021.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the value as converting the integer value to str.

I made my own sample dataframe to help your understanding. I used `Period` class of Pandas to save only year and month, but it can be converted to datetime type if needed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'val1': [2101, 2102, 2105, 2111],
        'val2': [2104, 2106, 2107, 2112],
     }
)

print(df)
#   val1  val2
#0  2101  2104
#1  2102  2106
#2  2105  2107
#3  2111  2112

def to_date(val):
    value = str(val)
    year_month = '20' + value[:2] + '-' + value[2:] # since you only need 2000s
    date_val = pd.Period(year_month, 'M') # used Period class to save only year and month, but it can be converted to datetime type if needed
    return date_val

df['date_val1'] = df['val1'].apply(to_date)
df['date_val2'] = df['val2'].apply(to_date)

print(df)
#   val1  val2 date_val1 date_val2
#0  2101  2104   2021-01   2021-04
#1  2102  2106   2021-02   2021-06
#2  2105  2107   2021-05   2021-07
#3  2111  2112   2021-11   2021-12
```

Comment: Heads up that this scheme will fail for dates earlier than 2010.

Comment: Thank you! how do I map it to a whole columns?

Comment: The code produces the result ``2021-01-01 00:00:00``, not ``2021-11-01 00:00:00`` (note the month).

Comment: @Hajarhajar What typs of column? on Pandas?

Comment: @SangkeunPark Yes pandas dataframe. Besides I am not interested in the day! just the year and the month

Comment: @Hajarhajar Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!